# Developing Android applications with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, android-ndk

I've recently obtained an HTC Desire and I'm interested in porting my 3D engine to the device.   I have a slight annoyance however.  I'd love to be able to do development under Visual Studio 2008.  Am I to assume I'm going to need to re-process my SLN files to do GCC builds?  Its not a vast issue as I already have an application that processes SLN and VCProj files through GCC and then links them together at the other end.  I'll just need to set up the right libraries with it.

Are there any other gotchas I need to think about?  Or, indeed, is there an easier way?

Any info would be much appreciated!

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use your own or the NDK supplied build system. I believe Visual Studio can be set up to call external commands to build. You can of course use Visual Studio as the code editor, and call the NDK supplied make on the Makefile to build your application. You can't use Visual Studio as a debugger.

Comment: Yeah I'd rather assumed on the debugger ;)  Thats not really a problem though ... even if I DO hate GDB :D  I've used a lot worse debuggers in fairness ... codewarrior's comes to mind ...

Answer (score 0):

Im not used with VS. Using it to develop android apps sounds like pain to me. Main reason is that i dont think it got any plugins for android as Eclipse does. I guess you can use it as pure Java IDE (??), but still... building, editing and syntax hightlighting, code-autocomplete, etc etc... will be missing...

Comment: It looks like the poster is planning to use the NDK, which is not Java (though still needs some slight interaction to bring up the application)

Comment: Well I can set up my custom build tool for VStudio and run the compiler through that.  Thats really not too much of an issue.  But rather than spend the required few hours setting up the build I was hoping someone would say ... HERES ONE I MADE EARLIER! :D

Answer (score -1):

Follow the instructions on using Ant to do builds and you should be able to figure out how to make the VS build process drive your apps.

I don't understand the desire to use such a terrible code editor, but anyone trying to set up their IDE to build Android apps should start with the Ant stuff that they document.

Comment: Perfect its not but I've still nto found a better alternative.  I've tried Dev-C++, Slickedit, Codewarrior and Code::Blocks ... all of which are FAR more terrible, IMO ... I miss Borland's editors personally ...

Answer (score -1):

Simply Put,

XCode + Eclipse + Carbide etc all cannot match the debugging environment of Visual Studio, GDB simply sucks our time.

These workaround tools just slow down the working process, to be honest working in xcode or esp eclipse seems like your thinking process is being overtaken by the management of bloatware that is required to manage the development in these forsaken IDE's. However Visual Studio development is more responsive and the IDE always seem to be prepared for any of your explorations

Regards
Bil