# What do I need to do to compile Android NDK (C++) aps in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: android, visual-studio

I've read in different places that this is possible.  I do not need to debug, just compile.  Any walkthrus out there?  Thx.

Found links:
[Android NDK with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056606/android-ndk-with-visual-studio) - "we've got it partially working, we use Visual Studio to build, using the proper android headers and whatnot, then we call the NDK build scripts. we're currently working on automating the second half as a post-build step"

http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/9f3a55366ba08f2a/cb539c80e5729032 - "You have to dig out proper parameters for all the tools, but I assure you 
that this all works for me on command-line (well actually in various bat 
files called from MS Visual Studio)."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Developing Android applications with Visual Studio 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836473/developing-android-applications-with-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: Setting up VS to work with Android, even if possible, will be much more pain than following the recommended path (NDK and Cygwin). You won't be able to debug anyway; why bother? As for using the VS editor, you can do that even now.

Comment: It works like a charm (http://www.gavpugh.com/2011/02/04/vs-android-developing-for-android-in-visual-studio), and you can also debug within Visual Studio using WinGDB for Android: http://ian-ni-lewis.blogspot.com/2011/01/its-like-coming-home-again.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building and debugging Android apps within Visual Studio is OK. No need to mess with Eclipse, or post build steps.

I've got it running myself, here is a screenshot:

[image]

http://www.gavpugh.com/2011/02/04/vs-android-developing-for-android-in-visual-studio/

In case you get "Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\tools.jar" you can add an environment variable JAVA_HOME that points to your Java JDK path, for example c:\sdks\glassfish3\jdk (restart MSVC afterwards)

If you like you can also debugg Android apps within MSVC using this:

http://ian-ni-lewis.blogspot.com/2011/01/its-like-coming-home-again.html

Download WinGDC for Android from http://www.wingdb.com/wgMobileEdition.htm

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft (obviously) doesn't seem interested in supporting this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/6641879e-6f47-403a-9ed5-28bb6e040563

Why not stick with Eclipse since that IDE will integrate with the compiler/debugger for the android target (including debugging the native library, I think).

Comment: Yeah, the OP is pretty much stuck with Eclipse.  It's a bit painful going from VS to Eclipse, but there is no sense in fighting a constant uphill battle with your tools.